# How to deal with multiple .proto files with the same package/message names?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

There are two different .proto files (say `foo.proto` and `bar.proto`) for different services where both use the package name `internal` and both define a `ToService` message. I need to use both protocols from the same program, but when I try to do that, I get duplicate symbol linker errors; both define `internal::ToService::~ToService` and other symbols in the `internal::` namespace.

I would really, really prefer to not have to modify the .proto files. How do I tell protoc to generate code in a different namespace than `internal`?